# Вывод сообщения, если вводимое число попало под заданный рандом

Tags: html, javascript

Нужно чтобы при вводе числа, если оно попадает в рандом, вывести сообщение

Форма (тут всё верно):

```
<form action='index.php' method="post">
Введите число:<br>
<input type="text" name="fnm" value="">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="отправить" name="Submit" onClick="return             Formdata(this.form)">
</form>
```

Сам скрипт:

```
function getRandom300(m,n){
return Math.floor(Math.random()*(n-m+1))+m;
}
function getRandom6(){
n6=getRandom300(50000,99999);
}
function Formdata(data){
if (data.fnm != n6)
{
alert('Число верно');
return false;}
```

Comment: Уточняющий вопрос: какой процент попаданий вы ожидаете? 0.002%?

Comment: В том то и дело, что нужно не попасть, а если число входит в этот отрезок, то вывести алерт. Решение простое, но не могу никак к нему прийти

Comment: Точнее будет, как записать интервал

    function getRandom300(m,n){

    function Formdata(data){

    if (data.fnm != [ЗДЕСЬ ИНТЕРВАЛ ОТ 50000 ДО 99999])

    {

    alert('Число верно');

    return false;}

Comment: Так зачем вы генерируете конкретное число? Если вам нужно узнать, что число находится в отрезке а...б, то сделайте проверку x > a && x < б

Comment: Сделал так, но не работает:

    function Formdata(data){
    if (data.fnm < 50000 || data.fnm > 99999)
    {
    alert('Число верно');
    return false;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ох

```
function validateNumber(number, lowerLimit, upperLimit) {
    number = parseInt(number);
    if (isNaN(number)) {
        throw new Error('Number is not a number -- what a joke, right?');
    }
    upperLimit = upperLimit || 99999;
    lowerLimit = lowerLimit || 50000;
    return number >= lowerLimit && number <= upperLimit;
}
```

Comment: Что-то он меня своим комментарием запутал... Плюсанул.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Связать не получается, вроде верно:
В шапке:

    <script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>

В html:

    Введите число:<br>
    <input type="text" name="number" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="отправить" name="Submit"     onClick="return validateNumber(this.form)">

Comment: @Rammsteinik, я не буду за вас писать все подряд. Эта функция принимает на вход число и сообщает, верное оно (возвращает true) или нет (возвращает false).

Comment: Я в этом новичёк, помогите связать с формой, смысл тогда было писать без связки =(

Comment: Это уже не первый раз, когда вы задаете вопрос, который, по сути, является работой за автора.